# DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, ora-00933

I keep getting the error "DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" when I run the following Python code. What is strange is that when I run the sql that I copied during debugging in SQuirrel, a database client, it works just fine. I'm using cx_Oracle. Does anyone have ideas what may be wrong? `names` is a dictionary and contains customer names in its value field. Thanks!

```
def getData(accts):
    names = getNames(list(accts))
    sql = """select 
         CustomerAcronym, 
         Portal, 
         CcyPair, 
         BuyCCY, 
         SellCCY, 
         count(PortalID) as TradeCount, 
         sum(BuyCCYAmt) as TtlBuyCcyAmt, 
         sum(SellCCYAmt) as TtlSellCcyAmt, 
         sum(USDEquiv) as USDEquivalent 
         from ( 
             select 
             CustomerAcronym, 
             Portal, 
             CcyPair, 
             case 
                 when DealtDirection = 'BUY' then DealtCcy 
                 when DealtCcy = CCY1 then CCY2 
                 else CCY1 
             end as BuyCCY, 
             case 
                 when DealtDirection = 'SELL' then DealtCcy 
                 when DealtCcy = CCY1 then CCY2 
                 else CCY1 
             end as SellCCY, 
             case 
                 when DealtDirection = 'BUY' then DealtAmount 
                 when DealtCcy = substr(Price, 1,3) and instr(Price,'/') = 0 then DealtAmount*substr(Price, instr(Price,' ')+1) 
                 when DealtCcy = substr(Price, 1,3) then DealtAmount*substr(Price, instr(Price,' ')+1, instr(Price,'/')-instr(Price,' ')-1) 
                 when DealtCcy = substr(Price, 4,3) and instr(Price,'/') = 0 then DealtAmount/substr(Price, instr(Price,' ')+1) 
                 when DealtCcy = substr(Price, 4,3) then DealtAmount/substr(Price, instr(Price,' ')+1, instr(Price,'/')-instr(Price,' ')-1) 
             end as BuyCCYAmt, 
             case 
                 when DealtDirection = 'SELL' then DealtAmount 
                 when DealtCcy = substr(Price, 1,3) and instr(Price,'/') = 0 then DealtAmount*substr(Price, instr(Price,' ')+1) 
                 when DealtCcy = substr(Price, 1,3) then DealtAmount*substr(Price, instr(Price,' ')+1, instr(Price,'/')-instr(Price,' ')-1) 
                 when DealtCcy = substr(Price, 4,3) and instr(Price,'/') = 0 then DealtAmount/substr(Price, instr(Price,' ')+1) 
                 when DealtCcy = substr(Price, 4,3) then DealtAmount/substr(Price, instr(Price,' ')+1, instr(Price,'/')-instr(Price,' ')-1) 
             end as SellCCYAmt, 
             PortalID, 
             USDEquiv 
             from SALES_DATA 
             where 
                 CustomerAcronym = 'ABCCORP' and 
                 DealtFlag = 'DEALT' and 
                 TDate > '2012-08-01' 
         ) as temptbl
         group by CustomerAcronym, Portal, CcyPair, BuyCCY, SellCCY 
         order by Portal, CcyPair"""
    con = getConn()
    try:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        return cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        con.close()
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that the method by which you are passing the argument does what you think it does. Your query is effectively `CustomerAcronym = :arg_1`, the use of `IN` here is not required because you have only one argument. But I can't see that this would cause ORA-00933.

Comment: Also, I think you're missing `CustomerAcronym` from your group by clause.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added `CustomerAcronym` in the group by clause and specified a client name in the where clause instead of using the IN stetement as edited above. But I'm still getting the same error and the sql works fine in SQuirrel.

Comment: yes, it's a mystery to me too. Do you have SQL*Plus? (personally I've had way too much trouble with SQuirrel to want to trust it)

Comment: It might be an unprintable character somewhere in your code. Why don't you determine the error position?

Comment: Jeffrey, I don't have SQL*Plus unfortunately.

Comment: steve, I tried copying the sql to Notepad and copying back it in the program to remove unprintable characters but still no luck. I'm not sure how I can determine the error position from my Python program. Could you tell me how we can do that or direct me to a documentation on that? Thanks!

Comment: I finally found out the problem. I hate to say but somehow I was connecting to a wrong server. I was working on two different programs and somehow confused myself. The SQL itself was ok. My apologies and thank you for your help.

Comment: @user1599687 If you solved the problem, please post an answer and accept it.